# Azure API management swagger/swashbuckle import gives error: Parsing error(s): Non-unique array item at index

Tags: azure, api, asp.net-core-2.1, swashbuckle, azure-api-management

I'm currently developing an API and using Swashbuckle to generate Swagger documentation. When I try to import it into Azure API Management I get the following errors if I use the [FromBody] on the in-parameter values on i.e. HttpPut or HttpPost methods:

```
Parsing error(s): Non-unique array item at index 15. Path 'paths./{Id}/settings.put.consumes[15]', line 1, position 2115.
```

If I remove it or replace with [FromQuery] it works and can be imported. I'm using .Net Core 2.1 and Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 4.0.1 and Swashbuckle.OData 3.5.0 since the project supports Odata.

The method giving the error looks like this:

```html
        /// <summary>
        /// AddOrUpdateSetting
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Updates a user's settings.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <param name="contactId"></param>
        /// <param name="setting"></param>
        /// <response code="200">The user setting was successfully updated.</response>
        /// <response code="400">Bad request (modelstate was invalid).</response>
        /// <response code="500">The request could not be processed.</response>
        [ProducesResponseType( typeof(IActionResult), Status200OK )]
        [ProducesResponseType( Status400BadRequest )]
        [ProducesResponseType( Status500InternalServerError )]
        [HttpPut( "{contactId}/settings" )]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddOrUpdateSetting(string contactId, [FromBody] UserSetting setting)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            await _notificationDataRepository.AddOrUpdateUserSetting(setting);

            return Ok(setting);
        }
```

The project was created using the API template in Visual Studio. Is this some kind of bug in the C# version of Swashbuckle or why is this occurring? FromBody is not unusual and should be supported I feel. Is this a limitation or is something else needed?

Comment: Is it working in local environment ? In my experience, swagger only crashes if you have duplicate name objects in the codebase, i.e., you have two classes named as ABC but are in different namespace.

Comment: Can you post generated swagger file?